# Did you give the ACC exam last year? Words that could replace 'give'

Tags: word-request

> Did you give the ACC exam last year?

Here, the word "give" sounds absurd. Is there some word(s) for replacement for *give* or maybe some word which is specially meant to be used for *exam* ?

Can you suggest a couple of such words?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the role being discussed? Is this a candidate taking the exam, the authority sponsoring the exam, someone overseeing the administration of the exam, or someone else?

Comment: This looks like a possible duplicate of [difference in verb collocation with exam](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/181312/difference-in-verb-collocation-with-exam) or [A professor takes/gives/sets exams](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69423/a-professor-takes-gives-sets-exams). Please [edit] your post to clarify who is "giving" the exam.

Comment: It might also be worth clarifying what dialect of English they're hoping to sound natural in, since it can vary by region.

Answer (score 11):

If you study for an exam, then sit down and answer the questions, then you are *taking* the exam. I’ve also heard “*sit* an exam”.

If you write down exam questions, then hand them out to your students, then you are *giving* the exam.

If you watch over students taking an exam, you are *proctoring* the exam.

Comment: **Invigilate** can also be used (in the same sense as *proctor*), especially in UK English.

Comment: In Canadian English, the most natural phrase for the first case is to _write_ an exam. This unfortunately causes confusion when mingling with our friends south of the border, as there, _writing_ an exam unequivocally means creating the questions!

Comment: @Schism I find *writing an exam* more less absurd than giving one.

Answer (score 6):

If by "give" you mean "handed out the exam and watched while the students *took* it" then it's perfectly idiomatic.

> Our History teacher **gave** us a pop quiz this morning, but I think I did OK.

Otherwise you can say *administer* a test, although this is more formal, and more common with standardized, official tests (such as  whatever the ACC is).  You would not normally write a test you *administer*, but only oversee the testing process.

*Proctor* similarly means to administer a test, although it usually is applied to the authorities in the room while the test is being taken.  Someone who *administers* a test might manage the group of people who *proctor* that test.

Answer (score 0):

For the context of a teacher writing an exam for their students to sit, the word "set" seems to work fine.

> I **set** my students a test on World History.
>
> Our maths teacher **set** us a hard test.

(This might be British English specific, but I see no reason why it wouldn't be understood any way.)

Comment: In American English I think people generally don't use this phrasing, but the meaning would probably be understood.